# Java Spring / Reactor send / update flux when underlying database changed

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I have a data for candidate "likes", which I'd like to send to client every time the "like" number is changed. I think this is achievable using Spring Flux? But I can't find any example for this. Most flux example is based on specific interval (e.g. every second). This might be a waste, because the transaction is not that much, and a candidate might not get likes in many minutes.
I just want to create dashboard that subscribe to "likes" change, and get updated when certain candidate "likes" number changed.

What is the way to get this?

This is what I did, and it works, but it based on interval (5 seconds), not based on data change.

```java
    public Flux<Candidate> subscribeItemChange(String id) {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).map(t -> candidateService.getCandidateDetail(id));
    }
```

The `candidateService.getCandidateDetail` is basically query database for certain id, so this is more like polling instead of "update on change".
I think I must put something on `candidateService.updateLikes()` below, but what should I update?

```java
public class CandidateService {

    public Candidate getCandidateDetail(String id) {
        // query candidate from database
        // select * from candidates where id = :id
        // and return it
    }
    
    
    public void updateLikes(String id, int likesCount) {
        // update candidates set likes_count = :likesCount where id = :id
        // ...
        // I think I need to write something here, but what?
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of a dynamic sink, adding a field similar to:

```
private Sinks.Many<Candidate> likesSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
```

...then you can:

- Use `sink.tryEmitNext` in your `updateLikes()` method to publish to the sink whenever likes are updated for a candidate;
- Implement your `subscribeItemChange()` method which uses `likesSink.asFlux()`, which can then be filtered if necessary to only return the stream of "like updates" for a particular candidate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, can you share a good reference (book / course / tutorial) for learn more about this flux thing?

Comment: @Timothy There's very little out there at the moment, unfortunately. I've considered writing some kind of book since there's so little around at the moment, but alas lack of time is always a bit of a blocker!

Comment: Keep in mind that is will not scale across multiple instances of a service, as only the instance that handles the write to the DB will notify it's local instance of the change. The db polling is the simplest way to communicate the change to multiple instances.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Michael Berry guide.

```java
    public void updateLikes(String id, int likesCount) {
        Candidate c = getCandidateDetail(id);
        c.setLikesCount(likesCount);

        CandidateDummyDatasource.likesSink.tryEmitNext(c);
    }
```

On subscriber

```java
    public Flux<Candidate> subscribeItemChange(String id) {
        return CandidateDummyDatasource.likesSink.asFlux()
                .filter(c -> c.getId().equals(id))
                .map(data -> candidateService.getCandidateDetail(id));
    }
```